# RSpec Rails printing undefined home_path error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, undefined, nameerror

When I run rspec on my rails project I get a very annoying error message, although exact the same code worked before. The only thing I did was adding a new rspec file. Now the new rspec file doesn't contain anything except for "require 'spec_helper'" but I still get this message (and a few others...):

> 1) Home Page should have 'Lists' and 'Students' links
>        Failure/Error: visit home_path
>        NameError:
>          undefined local variable or method `home_path' for > #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2:0x00000004c455a0>
>        # ./spec/requests/homes_spec.rb:5:in`block (2 levels) in '

I have no idea what to do now. Has anyone a clue what's the matter with it?

Thanks

Comment: Show your `$ rake routes` please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your routes proper helper would be `home_index_path`.
Try to use it.